# Why am I getting the error clearImmediate is not defined?

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, setimmediate, clearimmediate

i am trying to make an infinitive loop that stops when the video is uploaded. The function works fine, however to stop the loop does not seem to work. The error I get is:

> clearImmediate is not defined

this is the loop i am trying to make:

```
window.setImmediate = window.setTimeout; //had to add this for it to start the loop

var videoIsUploaded = false;

var immediateId;

function loop() {

    console.log('still uploading');

    immediateId = setImmediate(loop);

    if (videoIsUploaded == true) {

        window.clearImmediate(immediateId);

        HideTheUpload();
    }
}

loop();

function HideTheUpload(){

   document.getElementById("AddVideo").style.display = "none";

}
```

Once Azure has uploaded the video it sets "videoIsUploaded = true" this all works fine and the "if (videoIsUploaded..." fires

Comment: `window.clearImmediate` should be `window.clearTimeout`

Comment: There is no `clearImmediate` - you need to use `clearTimeout`. Or alias it like you do with `setImmediate`. Not sure why you do that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tl;Dr

**You should just use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.**

---

The nub of your problem appears to be you wanting to use `setImmediate`. This is a non-standard method that does not appear to be widely adopted in the web. See the [MDN site for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate):

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
>   use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
>   user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

and

> This method is not expected to become standard, and is only
>   implemented by recent builds of Internet Explorer and Node.js 0.10+.
>   It meets resistance both from Gecko (Firefox) and Webkit
>   (Google/Apple).

It looks like this is designed to work like an [async CPU bound operations](https://w3c.github.io/setImmediate/#si-setImmediate) but webkit and Mozilla disagreed with the implementation so it's been languishing since 2011.

It has been implemented in node.js. This almost certainly makes a lot more sense in a node.js app than it does in a web context, I'm presuming this is why node adopted it. I'm also presuming that you got this code from a node.js link?

I'm guessing that's why you're doing `window.setImmediate = window.setTimeout;`. But this is mostly pointless. You should just use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

BTW `clearImmediate` [does exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/clearImmediate) but it is again non-standard and not well supported.

Comment: thank you Liam for the great explination, code worked indeed and also was able to get rid off the window.setImmediate = window.setTimeout; idea came indeed from node.js

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in Javascript named `clearImmediate`.

Instead to clear timeout there is `clearTimeout`.

So,

Use

```
window.clearTimeout(immediateId);
```

Instead of

```
window.clearImmediate(immediateId);
```

Comment: There **is** a [clearImmediate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/clearImmediate) it's just not standardised